# User can't see Embedded Analytics dashboard in Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, einstein-analytics, isv, embedded, crm-analytics

What is needed for an ISV to **distribute** and for its subscribers without paid TCRM/Wave/Analytics licenses to **see** Dashboards from App Templates?

I have packaged a `type="embeddedapp"` template to a Managed Package, and it's correctly Auto-installed after package installation. Most of the stuff displayed in https://aquivalabs.quip.com/zhvtAlqU0k9q/Einstein-Analytics-Developer-LicenseBut when a Standard User of my app tries to display one of its dashboards on a Lightning page, he sees an access error:

> Error: You don’t have user access to view this component.

[image]

**Am I missing something important?**

1. Do I need to contact Salesforce to get Free Embedded licenses for my package?
2. Do I need to package special permissions to View Embedded Analytics?
3. Do I need to Enable something during Auto-Install?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the user have the permission set assigned correctly?
[image]

The freemium license is only available to OEMs on an active org. If you want to try it out, Since you are a PDO, I am assuming you have access to Environment Hub. You can create a PDE and log a case to have the licenses enabled. In the case of PDOs working for a customer ISV, ISv's Partner Account Manager (PAM) will have to get the embedded skus on the product catalog and provision on the customer's active org. For development activities, a case is sufficient.